How Moshe handled halachic disputes
I heard about a source in the Chumash regarding a situation where two people had a halachic dispute and could not conclude on the Halacha. They then went to Moshe to get the verdict but the wording of the verse says it in the singular to show that only one of them actually went to Moshe. The commentaries from here learned that it is good practice to act in this manner and if two people are really having this argument (whether financial or otherwise) for the sake of heaven then this is the way they should act to prove that they are really only after the “Dvar Hashem” and not to fight to prove that he is right

The verse said that “veyavo” and he came, which indicates of the two people arguing only one person came to ask Moshe what the Halacha was. Meaning we learn that if 2 people have a machloket, if their really arguing le Shem shamayim, only one of them will ask their Rabbi instead of both of them going

Thanks @RabbiKaii I’ve revised the question based on your feedback, I hope it’s more clear now

but isn't a judge forbidden from hearing a case without the litigants?

It wasn’t a case needing judgement, just to establish the Halacha I.e if this food kosher

Never heard that before. Sounds wrong.

@N.T. I’d be impressed if I made it up..truth is it could be about Aaron or somewhere in Nach with another king, I remembered Moshe but point is the occurrence of two people having a debate, coming to a teacher/leader/king but only one of them asking the question and relaying the answer to the other

Could be a gemara about a halachic dispute, not a personal one.

Yes very well could be, any idea as to a direction of where I could find it?

See Rambam Hilchos Talmud Torah 4:6

@User123 do you know what the Rambam’s source for that Halacha is? I saw Merkorot Hayad quote Tosefta Negaim 1:6 but I don’t see how that could be the source for it

Good vort! Thank you. Could you modify the question to reflect that it's about people asking Moshe (not a rabbi), and draw a conclusion that it's a good practice when asking a rabbi regarding a halachic dispute? Thank you!

Thank you! I appreciate the suggestion, certainly I will update it, also please feel free to edit it if you feel like any further changes should be made to make it more clear thanks

Wow B”H I found the answer after some extensive research Baruch Hashem! For anyone else looking , the source for this teaching is from Parashat Yitro 18:16

כִּֽי־יִהְיֶ֨ה לָהֶ֤ם דָּבָר֙ בָּ֣א אֵלַ֔י וְשָׁ֣פַטְתִּ֔י בֵּ֥ין
אִ֖ישׁ וּבֵ֣ין רֵעֵ֑הוּ וְהוֹדַעְתִּ֛י אֶת־חֻקֵּ֥י הָאֱלֹהִ֖ים
וְאֶת־תּוֹרֹתָֽיו׃
When they have a dispute, it comes before me, and I decide between one
party and another, and I make known the laws and teachings of God.”

On this verse Malbim, Gur Aryeh Divrei David and possibly more comment on the fact that the verse starts plural and then switches to singular and explain this exact principle. Divrei David actually wants to explain this using the Gemara in Bava Metzia 69a
B”H from my asking around I can see that this is not a very revealed teaching and I am very blessed to have originally heard it from a shiur so I tremendously hope it will now be able to reach others and we should keep sharing Torah with each other
